# "Application needs OAuth consent from the User" when saving a weight value to Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I am creating the GoogleApiClient instance with the following code:

```
    // Create the Google API Client
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(act)
        .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .enableAutoManage(act, 0, this)
        .build();
```

When the client is created, the phone shows the account selection dialog and then the OAuth authorization dialog. After that, the activity gets the result on the following method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG, "Result received");
    authInProgress = false;
    gf.connect();
}
```

On the log, I can see the authorization process working, but when trying to save into Google Fit, using the following code:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    calendar.setTime(now);
    long date = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder().
            setAppPackageName(activity).
            setDataType(dataType).
            setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW).
            build();
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.
            createDataPoint().
            setTimestamp(date, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    dataPoint.
            getValue(field).
            setFloat(value);
    dataSet.add(dataPoint);

    Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet).setResultCallback(cb);
```

I am seeing the following error:

> Application needs OAuth consent from the User

What am I missing? The OAuth credentials have been created in the Google Console.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: @noogui I have just solved by adding the scope as other mates said.

Answer (score 4):

You should add more Scope when init mClient:
Example:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(act)
    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ))
```

and more depending on which value you want to get data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're Google Developer Console is not the problem (API KEYs, Oauth, package name), make sure you included the scope specified [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization#OAuth2Authorizing).